# How to retrieve the last modification date of all files with specific extension in Git?

Tags: git

I know how to retrieve the last modification date of a single file in a Git repository:

```
git log -1 --format="%ad" -- path/to/file
```

Is there any way we can list last modification date of files with specific extension, like I say all files with `.config` extension?

Comment: As a sidenote, you *might* want to consider adding `--all` to your line (before the `-- path/to/file` of course), just in case the file has been modified in a recent branch and is unmerged (or if you need to execute the line while some "old" branch or commit is currently checked out). Then again, it might not be the result you expect, I was just mentioning the possible need.

Answer (score 3):

First, what you want to get is the last commit date. A file can be modified (on the system) while not having been committed.

To get the last committed date of all the config files, you can do something like:

```
find . -name "*.config" -exec sh -c 'echo "{} - $(git log -n 1 --pretty="format:%ad" {})"' \;
```

You can look at `man git-log` for the `pretty` option for different formatting if you need.